# Is it possible to get intermediate layer output after TensorRT?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorrt

We now have a trained network for classification task. The top of the network is like [image: top of the network]

so the layer **relu_fc1** is something like extracted features, then softmax to class prediction.

Now we want to extract these features directly. In normal case, we can do it by

`y = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('relu_fc1:0') sess.run(y,...)`

That's great, but we still want to make it faster, so we use TensorRT to convert the saved model. However, after the conversion, we can't get the right tensor in the **relu_fc1** because TensorRT mixed the operation up and produced something like TRTENgineOp_1.

I want to know is there a way to get the intermediate layer's output after TensorRT? I guess maybe it's easier for us can delete the last layers in the network then do the conversion, but can't find practical materials for removing the layers in tensorflow.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know is there a way to get the intermediate layer's output after TensorRT? I guess maybe it's easier for us can delete the last layers in the network then do the conversion, but can't find practical materials for removing the layers in tensorflow.

For this question, when you do the tf-to-onnx conversion, you can specify which layer as the final output for the onnx model. Then, you can do the [onnx-to-tensorrt](https://github.com/onnx/onnx-tensorrt) conversion.

For more details, see [tensorflow-onnx](https://github.com/onnx/tensorflow-onnx). The `--outputs` parameter is what you want.